# C# switch in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, switch-statement

Is it possible to have a switch in a lambda expression? If not, why? Resharper displays it as an error.

Comment: Does it compile? I wouldn't use Resharper as your final word on valid syntax.

Comment: Sure it doesn't and the compiled error is the same as resharper displayed output : A lambda expression with a statement boody cannot be convrted to an expression tree.

Comment: NB : I don't know what a statement body is.

Comment: "I don't know what a statement body is" - that is the difference between a lambda that starts with {/} braces (which *always* compiles to an anonymous method), and a lambda that doesn't (which can be compiled to an anonymous method **or** an expression-tree)

Comment: @Jeff - of course, the compiler isn't quite the final word either - but it sure is easier than trying to check against the spec ;-p Especially as the specifics of expression-tree translation is notoriously missing from the C# 3.0 / C# 4.0 specs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can in a statement block lambda:

```
Action<int> action = x =>
{
  switch(x)
  {
    case 0: Console.WriteLine("0"); break;
    default: Console.WriteLine("Not 0"); break;
  }
};
```

But you can't do it in a "single expression lambda", so this is invalid:

```
// This won't work
Expression<Func<int, int>> action = x =>
  switch(x)
  {
    case 0: return 0;
    default: return x + 1;
  };
```

This means you can't use switch in an expression tree (at least as generated by the C# compiler; I believe .NET 4.0 at least has support for it in the libraries).

Comment: yes indeed seems the issue is I want an expression tree. Is there any work around better than a if els if o a functino ?

Comment: A small correction (on hindsight... how much good is hindsight :-) ). The C# 4.0 Compiler still can't build "complex" `Expressions` (with `if`, `while`...) but you can build them through the use of the `Expression` class. The two things are decoupled. And with less hindsight: the OP asked about expression trees. The second `action` should have been an `Expression<Func<int, int>>` to show that you really wanted an Expression Tree and not a delegate.

Comment: It's been a while and C# 8 added switch expressions which allow you to

`Func<int, int> action = x => x switch {
      0 => 0,
      _ => x + 1
    };`

However, it is still not allowed in an expression tree for some reason

`Expression<Func<int, int>> action = x => x switch {
      0 => 0,
      _ => x + 1
    };`

Answer (score 13):

In a pure `Expression` (in .NET 3.5), the closest you can get is a compound conditional:

```
    Expression<Func<int, string>> func = x =>
        x == 1 ? "abc" : (
        x == 2 ? "def" : (
        x == 3 ? "ghi" :
                 "jkl")); /// yes, this is ugly as sin...
```

Not fun, especially when it gets complex. If you mean a lamda expression with a statement body (only for use with LINQ-to-Objects), then anything is legal inside the braces:

```
    Func<int, string> func = x => {
        switch (x){
            case 1:  return "abc";
            case 2:  return "def";
            case 3:  return "ghi";
            default: return "jkl";
        }
    };
```

Of course, you might be able to outsource the work; for example, LINQ-to-SQL allows you to map a scalar UDF (at the database) to a method on the data-context (that isn't actually used) - for example:

```
var qry = from cust in ctx.Customers
          select new {cust.Name, CustomerType = ctx.MapType(cust.TypeFlag) };
```

where `MapType` is a UDF that does the work at the db server.

Comment: You can omit the parentheses in your first code – the result is *much* less ugly and I actually use it sometimes. Admittedly, it takes a bit getting used to but it’s not inherently less readable than an equivalent `switch` block (less so, I’d argue).

Comment: Without the brackets I sometimes get lost in ? / : etc... but yes, it can work without them ;-p

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there still nothing better for a pure `Expression` in .Net 4.0?

Comment: @ken2k yes and no; the `Expression` API includes full block support, including [`Expression.Switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd630254.aspx) - however, the question here is about *lambdas*; the C# lambda-to-`Expression` compiler has not changed to include support for the wider `Expression` syntax now available.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the information. I'll use the syntax you provided in your first code, it's the most readable indentation I've found yet :) Let's hope the next version of C# language/compiler will provide something better.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it works, but you have to put your code in a block.  Example:

```
private bool DoSomething(Func<string, bool> callback)
{
    return callback("FOO");
}
```

Then, to call it:

```
DoSomething(val =>
                {
                    switch (val)
                    {
                        case "Foo":
                            return true;

                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in a statement block lambda:

```
public static string CarBrandIdNotExist(AppLanguage language) => language switch
    {
        AppLanguage.English => "CarBrandId not exist",
        AppLanguage.Arabic => "CarBrandId not exist",
        AppLanguage.India => "CarBrandId not exist",
        AppLanguage.Filipino => "CarBrandId not exist",
        _ => "CarBrandId not exist",
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I see no reason why this shouldn't work. Just be careful with the syntax you use

```
param => {
    // Nearly any code!
}

delegate (param) {
    // Nearly any code!
}

param => JustASingleExpression (No switches)
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked it too :-)

```
[Test]
public void SwitchInLambda()
{
    TakeALambda(i => {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 2:
                return "Smurf";
            default:
                return "Gnurf";
        }
    });
}

public void TakeALambda(Func<int, string> func)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(func(2));
}
```

Works just fine (outputs "Smurf")!

Comment: Because that isn't an Lambda Expression. A **Lambda Expression** would be of type `Expression<Func<int, string>>`. That is a **Lambda Function**. Try changin the input parameter of TakeALambda and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just learn this:

```
                      (model) =>
                                {
                                    switch(model.SentInvoiceTypeId)
                                    {
                                        case 1:
                                            return "1 asdf";
                                        case 2:
                                            return "2 asdf";
                                        case 3:
                                            return "3 asdf ";
                                        case 4:
                                            return "4 asdf ";
                                        default:
                                            return "asdf";
                                    }
                                }
```

Just put between the "model" () and add  your code in {   }, remember to have a return.
I am not sure in which versions of C# will work, In this example is the C# 7.0

I hope this answer can help someone.